# Check text file format in java

Tags: java

I have the code to check a text file line-by-line but I am unsure how to check for a specific format.  If the text file is in the following format print out the content, otherwise dipslay a message saying "File is not correct."

The first line of the should start with an S, and every line consists of any upper-case, followed by a colon, than any letter, number or e.

Comment: String has a `startsWith(...)` method that you may wish to use.

Comment: I am unsure about how this is solvable using Java API methods, but the general topic you should focus your research on is "parsing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to easily validate the format:

```
//first line validator:
String reg1 = "S:[A-Z01e]";
//next lines validator:
String reg2 = "V:[A-Z01e]?[A-Z01e]?[A-Z01e]";

//examples/test cases:
System.out.println("S:1".matches(reg1));
System.out.println("S:3".matches(reg1));
System.out.println("S:11".matches(reg1));
    
System.out.println("V:1e0".matches(reg2));
System.out.println("V:1e01".matches(reg2));
System.out.println("V:1e3".matches(reg2));
```

The regex is: First `S` or `V` respectively, then `:`, and then any character between A-Z ot 0 or 1 or e.

The `?` means 0 or one repeats, so `[A-Z01e]?[A-Z01e]?[A-Z01e]` means 1-3 characters, each A-Z or 0 or 1 or e.

Comment: I think I would like to use this, I've been looking into regular expressions and this seems like a good path to go.  Is there any tips for how to implement this in my code? I've used regular expressions in javascript but I do not think that has really prepared me for doing it in Java.  Thank you!

Comment: @infiniteSet: Nothing special, just read the tutorial I linked to and start practicing - it will help you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `charAt(1)` on each line.

```
scan.nextLine();
String line = scanner.next();
if(line.charAt(0).equals("S")) {

} else {

}
```

I'm pretty certain thats how it would work

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this: [Regex Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex)

For example, to check for `V:xxx`, you can use:

```
V:[A-Z01e]{3}
```

Where the number in curly braces is how many x's you want.